# How to show $nP\{|X|>n\}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, but $X$ is not integrable.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

How can I construct a random variable $X$ such that: $nP\{|X|>n\}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, but $X$ is not integrable.

Comment: $E[|X|] = \int_0^{\infty} t P(|X|>t)dt$, think about if you take $t P(|X|>t) = \dfrac{C}{t\log(t)}$, when $t$ is large.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

An application of Fubini's theorem gives that for a non-negative random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$, 
$$E(X)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mu(X>t)dt.$$
Take $X$ such that $\mu(X>t)=\frac C{t\log t}$ for $t\geqslant 2$, where $C$ is a normalizing constant. Then $E(X)$ is infinite according to the previous formula, but $n\cdot\mu(X>n)=\frac C{\log n}\to 0$.

However, if $X$ is integrable then $n\mu(|X|>n)\to 0$.